# problem with an adapter in android app

Tags: android, adapter

I have an app in android in which I return some data from `facebook`(some names and id's) and right after I return this data I use an adapter to set all this names in a list view.
All this work I do it in `onCreate()`.First time I use a method  `getData()` to return some names from facebook and after that I call for the adapter.

The problem is that `getData()` returns in an `array` of Strings the names that will be setup up with the adapter.Now,the adapter called does some processing on this array.

How I return these names from web this part works slowly and the array is not filled in time so when the adapter gets called the array is still empty and I get force close.

this is how I do it:

```
private String[] mStrings;
private String[] fName;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.invitefriends);

        ....................
   /*In here I request for friends from facebook which ae set up in an array*/
     mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new SampleRequestListener());

  /*here is the adapter that processes the arrays returned in SampleRequestListener*/

    adapter=new LazyAdapter1(this, mStrings,fName);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
```

/*Here is the SampleRequestListener that does return from facebook the names in some arrays*/

```
public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener{
    int i;
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state){
        friends = new ArrayList<Friends>();
        try{
            Log.d("facebook-example","Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            JSONArray array = json.optJSONArray("data");


            if(array!=null){
                for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
                {
                    String name=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    String id= array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                    Friends f=new Friends(name,id);
                    friends.add(f);
                    Log.d(name,id);
                }
                   mStrings = new String[friends.size()];
                    for(int i=0; i< mStrings.length; i++){
                        mStrings[i] = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+friends.get(i).getId()+"/picture?type=small";
                    }
                    fName = new String[friends.size()];
                    for(int i=0; i<friends.size(); i++)
                    {
                        fName[i]=friends.get(i).getName();
                    }

            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        catch(FacebookError e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the adapter's body:

public class LazyAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] nume;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter1(Activity a, String[] d, String[] f) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    nume=f;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //........
}
```

}

The problem is that `mStrings[]` and `fName[]` are not returned in time by the background thread so they are still empty when I try to act with the adapter on them.

So could someone tell how should I proceed for this thing to work right??Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the AsyncTask class and extend with your custom class.

this was good for getting the data in background process.

and when the data are fetched then set into the adapter

check this links

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to delay the setup of the adapter!!

Comment: in this 3 method which was override it 1st doInBackground so fetch all the data in this portion, 2 was onProgressUpdate it for display loading portion as ui to the user and last onPostExecute here when the array was prepared in the background process set this array into the adapter. you don't need to set time when the background process was complete, it will call the onPostExecute method